# how can i update a checkbox based on AboutMe and FullPhotoUrl fields?

Tags: chatter, user

I need to update a checkbox based on the values of AboutMe and FullPhotoUrl fields on User object.

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Nirmala.

Comment: Where is this checkbox? What have you tried?

Comment: Agreed, if you're going to ask us how to do your homework you should at least provide us enough detail to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to implement a trigger. e.g.

```
trigger onUser (before insert, before update)
{
    for(User u : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(u.AboutMe != null)
        {
            u.customCheckbox__c = true;
        }
        if(u.FullPhotoUrl != null)
        {
            u.customCheckbox2__c = true;
        }
    }
}
```